# Swift Index Out of Range for Attribute

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm receiving an Index out of Range runtime error for the code below. It seems pretty straightforward, so I'm pretty surprised an issue is coming up. If someone could help me in debugging this it would be appreciated

```
import SwiftUI

struct sampleView: View {

    var foo: Foo = Foo(name: "Mark Johnson", images: [Image("IMG_1039")])

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{

                foo.images[0].resizable()  // this line raises the error
                    .frame(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point. However, when I replace foo.images[0] with Image("IMG_1039") it works perfectly

Comment: That's pretty much it. I also tried replacing the image with a system image, and it still worked. The breakpoint shows that everything initializes properly except for the images attribute

Comment: Sorry, for the last comment - with the system image it still **didn't** work. Tried with @State and still giving me issues

Comment: Can you reduce it to a tiny project and upload it to github or similar so I can try running it? I can't reproduce the issue from the code you've shown, so something must be going on in some region you haven't shown.

Comment: Sure, I'll send a link in an hour or so

Comment: Works fine here. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2. Are you sure your `IMG_1039` is in `Assets.xcassets`?

Comment: what is Foo ?? how is it implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the issue with the use variable before it's initialising. So I try to initialise the variable foo and it working fine.

```
struct Foo {
    var name : String
    var images : [Image]
}

struct sampleView : View {
    var foo : Foo


    init() {
        self.foo = Foo(name: "Mark Johnson", images: [Image("IMG_1039")]) 
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                foo.images[0].resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It woking fine now with out any issue.
Quick look into the Attached screen shot
[image]

***Hope It will helps to you. 
Happy Coding.....***

Comment: I'd describe this as a bug in SwiftUI, if you can't rely on a self-initialized property to be initialized before the `view` body runs. Even if the bug is that the compiler ought to warn... :)